# Find $\alpha$ if AB = 2HM

Tags: geometry

[image]

My progress

I haven't made much progress. I figured out the angles but all the equations are equivalent. I think some additional straight will be needed.
I plotted H, D midpoint of AB, so AD = DB = x. Therefore:
$\triangle ADH (isosceles) \triangle DHB (isosceles)...$
(Answer: $\alpha =18ô$
[image]

Comment: @TheSimpliFire ..sorry, adjusted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join D to M and mark intersection of DM and BH as F. we have:

$DM||AC\Rightarrow \angle FMH=\angle MAF=\alpha$

Triangle DHM is isosceles so:

$\angle HDF=\alpha$

$\angle DFH=90+\alpha$

So: $\angle DHB=180-(90+\alpha+\alpha)=90-2\alpha$

Triangle BDH is isosceles and we have:

$\angle DBH=\angle DHB$

So:

$3\alpha=90--2\alpha\Rightarrow \alpha=18^o $

Comment: Only one fix at the end...$\alpha = 18^o$...Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: <FMD =$\alpha$ ??? i don't understood

Comment: @petaarantes, sorry , was a typo , I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let point $D$ be midpoint of $AB$, $AD=BD$

Draw $HD$, then $HD=AD=BD=HM$

Draw $DM$, then $\triangle HDM$  is an isosceles with $HD=HM$

$DM \parallel AG$, since $AD=BD$ and $BM=MG$ (Midpoint Theorem)

$\angle AMD= \angle MAG= \alpha$, then $\angle HDM=\angle AMD = \alpha$

$\angle DHA =2\alpha$ (exterior angle of triangle $HDM$)

$\angle DAH =\angle DHA =2\alpha$ $(AD=DH)$

$5\alpha =90$ (in triangle ABH)

$\alpha=18$